# Missing script : "start" while running npm start even though package.json is at the right place with all the scripts in it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, npm-start

Missing script : "Start" while running npm start even though package.json file is in the directory with scripts in it

```
{
  "name": "typee",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.34",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.7",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my package.json file after running

npx create-react-app typee --template typescript

when I try to run npm start

I get this

Missing script : "start"

Comment: The correct command is `npm run start`

Comment: hope you have execute `cd typee` and then `npm run start`. is it ?